# SAS replacing second character letter o to zero 0 in a pattern

Tags: regex, sas

I tried this code.

```
DATA want;
PATTERN = PRXPARSE ("s/([cu])[o]([0-9a-z][0-9][0-9a-z])/$10$2/");
text="there was a co545 code in code c 0678";
RETAIN PATTERN;
CALL PRXCHANGE(PATTERN, -1, text); 
run;
```

The result was "there was a 545 code in code c 0678"
How do I change my code to achieve "there was a c0545 code in code c 0678? All I want is to change letter o to zero(second character)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something to make it understand you want `$1` and not `$10`. From this website:  http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html

```
Putting curly braces around the digit ${1} isolates the digit from any 
literal digits that follow.
```

So use:

```
PATTERN = PRXPARSE ("s/([cu])[o]([0-9a-z][0-9][0-9a-z])/${1}0$2/");
```

Answer (score 0):

By performing two steps  first by introducing space and later the next step to remove the space.

```
DATA want;
PATTERN = PRXPARSE ("s/([cu])[o]([0-9a-z][0-9][0-9a-z])/$1 0$2/");
PATTERN1 = PRXPARSE("s/([cu])\s([0-9a-z][0-9][0-9a-z]/$1$2/");
text="there was a co545 code in code c 0678";
RETAIN PATTERN;
RETAIN PATTERN1;
CALL PRXCHANGE(PATTERN, -1, text); 
CALL PRXCHANGE(PATTERN1, -1, text);
run;
```